# How to disable a bootstrap icon hover

Tags: bootstrap-4, hover, icons, disable

I am using this icon definition:

```
<svg class="bi bi-arrow-repeat arrow-success" id="id-topdashboard-icon-refresh" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="ViewFunctionFront_ShuffleMapCitiesButton()">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4 9.5a.5.5 0 00-.5.5 6.5 6.5 0 0012.13 3.25.5.5 0 00-.866-.5A5.5 5.5 0 014.5 10a.5.5 0 00-.5-.5z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M4.354 9.146a.5.5 0 00-.708 0l-2 2a.5.5 0 00.708.708L4 10.207l1.646 1.647a.5.5 0 00.708-.708l-2-2zM15.947 10.5a.5.5 0 00.5-.5 6.5 6.5 0 00-12.13-3.25.5.5 0 10.866.5A5.5 5.5 0 0115.448 10a.5.5 0 00.5.5z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M18.354 8.146a.5.5 0 00-.708 0L16 9.793l-1.646-1.647a.5.5 0 00-.708.708l2 2a.5.5 0 00.708 0l2-2a.5.5 0 000-.708z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
                                    </svg>
```

And I want to "disable it" at some point, temporarily.
I use this in the code, it works fine:

```
            $('#id-topdashboard-icon-refresh').prop('disabled', true);
```

But the icon "hover" is still there.

Cannot seem to find the right "line" of code to do the same 'disable' for the hover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`disabled` is preserved for some form `<input>`/`<select>` elements.

You can add toggle a class instead to disable pointer events:

```js
$('.arrow-success1').addClass('disabled');
```

```css
.arrow-success:hover{
  fill:red
}

.disabled{
  fill:#ccc;
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg class="bi bi-arrow-repeat arrow-success"  width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="ViewFunctionFront_ShuffleMapCitiesButton()">
  <path d="M4 9.5a.5.5 0 00-.5.5 6.5 6.5 0 0012.13 3.25.5.5 0 00-.866-.5A5.5 5.5 0 014.5 10a.5.5 0 00-.5-.5z M4.354 9.146a.5.5 0 00-.708 0l-2 2a.5.5 0 00.708.708L4 10.207l1.646 1.647a.5.5 0 00.708-.708l-2-2zM15.947 10.5a.5.5 0 00.5-.5 6.5 6.5 0 00-12.13-3.25.5.5 0 10.866.5A5.5 5.5 0 0115.448 10a.5.5 0 00.5.5z
M18.354 8.146a.5.5 0 00-.708 0L16 9.793l-1.646-1.647a.5.5 0 00-.708.708l2 2a.5.5 0 00.708 0l2-2a.5.5 0 000-.708z" />
</svg>

<svg class="bi bi-arrow-repeat arrow-success arrow-success1"  width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" onclick="ViewFunctionFront_ShuffleMapCitiesButton()">
  <path d="M4 9.5a.5.5 0 00-.5.5 6.5 6.5 0 0012.13 3.25.5.5 0 00-.866-.5A5.5 5.5 0 014.5 10a.5.5 0 00-.5-.5z M4.354 9.146a.5.5 0 00-.708 0l-2 2a.5.5 0 00.708.708L4 10.207l1.646 1.647a.5.5 0 00.708-.708l-2-2zM15.947 10.5a.5.5 0 00.5-.5 6.5 6.5 0 00-12.13-3.25.5.5 0 10.866.5A5.5 5.5 0 0115.448 10a.5.5 0 00.5.5z
M18.354 8.146a.5.5 0 00-.708 0L16 9.793l-1.646-1.647a.5.5 0 00-.708.708l2 2a.5.5 0 00.708 0l2-2a.5.5 0 000-.708z" />
</svg>
```